# PHP Code assistance

Tags: php

I have the following code to post to a MySQL database and send an email containing the data. It all works, but the email does not contain the actual variable data, just the other email txt. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO mes_demo (`first`, `last`, email, credit_union, `date`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['first'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['last'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['credit_union'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "date"));

 mysql_select_db($database_MESdemo, $MESdemo);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $MESdemo) or die(mysql_error());

$to = "mike@michaelneill.com;tony@michaelneill.com";
$subject = "MES Demo Viewed";
$txt = "The following person has submitted a form to view the MES Demo\r\n
Name: $first $last\r\n
E-mail: $email\r\n
Credit Union: $credit_union";
$headers = "From: Tony Hendrix <tony@michaelneil.com>";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

$insertGoTo = "demo.html";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is some old PHP code you are working with as it seems to be using PHP register_globals which was deprecated in PHP 5.3 and finally removed from PHP 5.4

You can learn more about it here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

However as others have pointed you, you must define these variables first:

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$credit_union = $_POST['credit_union'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

Secondly, if you don't want to change. You should look at extract() function: http://php.net/extract

Try putting this first:

```
extract($_POST);
```

like this:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);

$to = "mike@michaelneill.com;tony@michaelneill.com";
$subject = "MES Demo Viewed";
$txt = "The following person has submitted a form to view the MES Demo\r\n
Name: $first $last\r\n
E-mail: $email\r\n
Credit Union: $credit_union";
$headers = "From: Tony Hendrix <tony@michaelneil.com>";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use variables like `$first` and `$credit_union` without defining them.

Either use `$_POST['first']` instead, or define the variables you are trying to use:

`$first = $_POST['first']`

Answer (score 0):

after/or before your $insertSQL , define PHP variables like below, so you can access. If undefined it will be blank.

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$credit_union = $_POST['credit_union'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
```